# Не отображаются боковые границы QGroupBox

Tags: css, qt5

У меня есть приложение Qt и в одном окне внутри QScrollArea и verticalLayout есть QGroupBox с таким css:

```
#groupBox { background-color: transparent;
border-color: black; 
border-width: 1 px; 
border-style: solid; 
margin: 5px; }
```

Вместо ожидаемого результата, я получаю вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я могу смириться с верхним пробелом в границе, это не важно. Но куда делись боковые границы?
Увеличение отступов padding/marging работает, но не исправляет проблемы, как и ограничение максимальной ширины GroupBox.

Comment: html в студию, скорее всего весь текст нужно обволочить в отдельный див и дать этому диву бордер, а потом ессесно падингами этого дива вытолкать текст

Comment: Исходник автогенерируется в xml Qt Designer'ом. Но проблема уже решена

Answer (score 1):

В чем суть, не понятно, но замена трех строчек на одну работает как надо:

```
border: 1px solid black;
```